# Factorization of the identity element of the free monoid

Tags: abstract-algebra, semigroups, monoid

Let $X$ be a set and let $\text{Mo}(X)=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} X^{[1,n]}$. Then $\text{Mo}(X)$ together with the law $(w,w')\mapsto ww'$, where $ww'$ denotes the juxtaposition of the sequences $w$ and $w'$, is a monoid. The identity element of $\text{Mo}(X)$ is the unique empty sequence $e\in X^{[1,0]}$.

We have the following convention:

> Let $M$ be a monoid with a multiplicative law. If $(x_\alpha)_{\alpha\in\emptyset}$ is the empty
>   family of elements of $M$, then $\prod_{\alpha\in\emptyset}
>  x_\alpha=e$.

We also have the following result:

> If $w=(x_i)_{1\leq i\leq n}$ for $x\in X^{[1,n]}$ and
>   $n\in\mathbb{N}$, then $w=\prod_{i=1}^nx_i$.

Now, let $w=(x_i)_{1\leq i\leq 0}$ for $x\in X^{[1,0]}$: i.e. $w=e$. By our convention, the composition of the family $(y_\alpha)_{\alpha\in\emptyset}$ of **elements of $\text{Mo}(X)$** is equal to $e$: that is,
$$e=\prod_{\alpha\in\emptyset}y_\alpha$$
for $y\in\text{Mo}(X)^{\emptyset}$. But $x\in X^\emptyset$ and not in $\text{Mo}(X)^{\emptyset}$, so it cannot be that $e=\prod_{i=1}^0x_i$.

How can I resolve this? Should I say that $X^\emptyset=\text{Mo}(X)^\emptyset$ (but this seems dubious)?

Comment: I'm not sure why you think that $x$ would need to be in $\text{Mo}(X)^{\emptyset}$.  None of this is special to the empty set; you could ask the exact same question for any other situation where you write an element of $\text{Mo}(X)$ as a product of elements of $\text{Mo}(X)$.

Comment: I invite you to switch to standard notation. The free monoid over $X$ is usually denoted $X^*$, its elements are words, written as $x_1x_2 \dotsm x_n$, where $n$ is the length of the word, the set of words of length $n$ is denoted by $X^n$, and the empty word, which is the identity of the free monoid, is denoted by $1$.